# Can I use JSON4S hashCode method as a key?

Tags: scala, json4s

Is it a right approach to use JSON4S hashCode JValue method as a key to store json in key-value store? I am embarrassed about it's length and possible collisions.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on this hash func. Why not just using a GUID?

Answer (score 0):

I found a Birthday Paradox. Wiki page has a probability table wich demonstrates that with the hashCode size of a 32 bits you have a 50% chance to hit a collision if you have more than 77000 objects to hash. So in my case i nedd more than 500000 keys to store.
So answer is "No" in my case, but depends on the final size of the key collection.

Comment: Collision mostly depends from implementation of function under the hood, and 77000 is not critical threshold to collision.

Comment: It is a 50% chance for hit a collision, with 1.1 × 10⁵ it is a 75% chance, so with 500K keys it will tends to 100% chance. And only one collision in my case it's a big problem with 70M subscribers with links on the wrong data.

Comment: If you use `UUID` for 500000 keys, it will work fine, don't be afraid about collision with `UUID`